# Why does "inline" or "inline-block" cause the <div> to disappear?

Tags: html, css

In the CSS `div div`, I set the `display` property value to `inline` and the `.nav` classed `<div>` in the HTML disappeared. The `.nav` classed `<div>` appears only if I remove the `display: inline;` property.

Here is my code:

```css
* {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

div div {
  display: inline;
}

.nav {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav">
      <h2>Menu Bar<h2>
      <ul><li>Option1</li><li>Option2</li><li>Option3</li></ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <h1>Site Title</h1>
      <p id="dp">Here is the paragraph.<p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Please fix it first.

Comment: @SawZinMinTun Please don’t suggest edits to _fix_ broken code in the question.

Comment: As you can see, the `div` does not disappear, but the `background-color` does not show properly. Use `display: inline-block` instead.

Comment: `div div { ... }` is an *awful* way to do CSS.

Comment: @EdmundReed Yeah, universal selector for setting `font-family` is also bad.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you have added block level element `<h2>` inside the `.nav` div which is right now having the inline property.

If you still want inline property to .nav then please apply the same display inline property to child elements i.e. h2 or change the property of `div div { display: inline-block; }`, but it's a wrong practice to keep block level elements inside inline elements.